# Can an Automator workflow generate an Application?

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm building a "Wizard" of sorts that uses Automator and some Appliescript, and at the end I would like it to generate an "Automator Application" that does things when launched, that are based on the inputs from the wizard.

Is this even possible?  Can one Automator workflow, actually generate an application from the results?  I know software can create software, but is this possible within Automator's capabilities?

**EDIT:  As noted in the comments below the post, `osacompile` seems like it might get me where I want to go, but now I have a new problem with that.**

Here's a screenshot of my automator steps:

[image: Automator routine]

Here's the code of the erroring module (Send iMessage):

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    set sms_address to item 1 of input
    set email_address to item 2 of input
    set sms_content to item 3 of input
    set email_subject to item 4 of input
    set email_body to item 5 of input
    
    set savePath to (path to desktop as text) & "test.scpt"
    
    set code to "osacompile -e 'tell application \"Messages\"' -e ' 
    set imessageservice to 1st service whose service type = iMessage' -e '
    set iMessageBuddy to buddy " & sms_address & " of imessageservice' -e '
    send " & sms_content & " to iMessageBuddy' -e '
    end tell' -o " & quoted form of POSIX path of savePath
    
    do shell script code
    
    return input
end run
```

Note that the lines are broken up that way because it was the only approach I could find where I didn't get any errors just because of adding line breaks (I can put this code all on one line and get the identical error)

Here's the error I receive:

[image: osacompile error message]

I haven't been able to figure out what the problem is here but it seems like I'm not passing the variables in the way a bash script expects.  Have tried a bunch of other approaches and nothing has worked any better, but this is the one that seems the most sensible to me, knowing how I would normally pass variables into a script.

**EDIT 2:  To simplify further, here is the standalone code I'm current debugging in AppleScript Editor and without any line breaks to not confuse the issue:**

```
set sms_address to "person@gmail.com"
set sms_content to "sms content"

set savePath to (path to desktop as text) & "test.scpt"

set code to "osacompile -e 'tell application \"Messages\"' -e ' set imessageservice to 1st service whose service type = iMessage' -e 'set iMessageBuddy to buddy " & sms_address & " of imessageservice' -e 'send " & sms_content & " to iMessageBuddy' -e 'end tell' -o " & quoted form of POSIX path of savePath

do shell script code
```

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to build an Automator _application_, but the `osacompile` shell utility can be used to create applets.  What kind of "inputs" are you trying to use?

Comment: I'm trying to create a simple program so I can schedule text messages and emails to myself to remind me of certain things.  I want to prompt for things like the phone number to use, email subject line and body, etc. and then compile that into an application that will execute the javascripts to send a text or create an email using those previously inputted values.  Once there is an application, then I can create a calendar event that will trigger the app at the desired time.  For now compiling the app is my big obstacle.

Comment: It's possible I've got a lead on the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817752/programmatically-create-apple-script and thanks to you mentioning `osacompile`.  If I get something that works, I'll answer the question assuming nobody else has by then.

Comment: So this is showing great promise, but I can't manage to pass a variable (from `input`) into the shell script without throwing an error.  Is there some special method for passing a variable in?  I tried using double quotes to drop out of the `osacompile` and back again, but no go.  What am I missing here... seems like this should be simple.  I'm very close to an elegant and complete answer.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing some code, but note that the `input` argument is a _list_, so you would need to coerce, repeat through it, or get an item from it.

Comment: Code examples and error messages added to OP.

Comment: Yeah I know that's where the problem lies, but I've tried numerous other approaches and none have worked.  What would a "proper break" be?  Every other approach I tried to get line breaks to work would error out.  This one errors out identically if it's all on one line or like this.  If I delete the variable insertion attempts on the 3rd and 4th lines of the osacompile, the code compiles just fine as-is.

Comment: OK, well I have updated the post to include the code I'm troubleshooting now, that has it all on one line so as to remove that point from the discussion.  No change, just the same compile error.

Comment: Solved it!  Forgot that the content being passed in needed to be quoted in the final script.  Will post an answer now.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted the code sections to be more easily readable.  Having it all in one line is just completely un-de-buggable for me so unless there's actually some sort of advantage to having it all on one line, I far prefer this method.

Comment: What I was saying is that you _can_ use multiple lines with just a single `-e` option, you don't have to break it up into individual statements, and it doesn't have to be all on one line.  You can copy an entire script into a string, formatting and all (Script Debugger makes escaping quotes and whatever easy), then use that string with a single `-e` option.

Comment: Gotcha.  I had just figured that out actually right before you posted this, but I appreciate the extra input!

Comment: Consider using a heredoc (`<<`), which would completely remove any ambiguity about quoting and line breaks, as you would input the script contents into a heredoc identically to how you would into Script Editor.

Comment: In fact I played around with that as well but it was giving me issues so I just stuck with what worked.  But good suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

So from the edits to my post, I was on the right track.  But I forgot that the final script needs to have quotes around the content being passed in!  This is the code snippet that ultimately worked:

```
set sms_address to "sms_address"
set sms_body to "sms_body"
set filename to "filename"
set savePath to (path to desktop as text) & filename & ".scpt"

set code to "osacompile -e '
tell application \"Messages\" 
    set imessageservice to 1st service whose service type = iMessage 
    set iMessageBuddy to buddy \"sms_address\" of imessageservice 
    send \"sms_body\" to iMessageBuddy
end tell' -o " & quoted form of POSIX path of savePath

do shell script code
```

So I was on the right path all along, just needed to excape those double quotes.