# how to create a repeating event in Automator?

Tags: applescript, automator, calendar, ical

I would like to programmatically create a repeating event.  I'm using Automator and it seems that Automator can't do this, plus I want to pass variables provided by the user into the event creation process so I'm guessing I need to do it in AppleScript instead.  Trouble is I haven't been able to find information on how to do that.

How can I create a recurring event in Automator using AppleScript (or really any other way would be worthy of note as well)?

Comment: In theory, this can be done by setting a calendar alarm that triggers an Automator workflow to run.  But I'd personally due it by way of `launchd`.

Comment: OK so basically it can’t be done… There is no actual way to create a genuine repeating event like you would manually, you have to fake it with some sort of scheduled action? What a shame.

Comment: Perhaps I misspoke.  The “calendar alarm” is a builtin function of Automator, which you should see when you go to create a new workflow, for which one of the options is called _”Calendar Alarm”_. The description provided when selected states _”Calendar Alarms are workflows that are run when triggered by an event in Calendar. They receive no input.”_ What is it you’re wanting to do ?  Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you mean by “repeating event” ?

Comment: I just want to programmatically (as in, via AppleScript) create a repeating calendar alert that triggers an application.

Comment: Automator has a `New Calendar Event` action that can trigger (by which I assume you mean “open”) an application. An AppleScript action before and after this can be used to obtain user input—which can be assigned to Automator variables (`Set Variable` action)—to set the specifics of the event, and, following its creation, script its recurrence.

Comment: But, I don’t think Automator is the right tool for this.  If you go the `launchd` approach, you can create a recurring event (it won’t be an event that appears in Calendar, but that doesn’t sound necessary here). The event can open an application, run an AppleScript, etc.  And, creating a `launchd` property list file is easy with AppleScript, meaning you can automate the whole thing.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if we're talking about the same thing or not.  I know I can manually create an event in automator, but it doesn't seem to allow for *repeating* events.  I want to create a repeating event via AppleScript, which is being generated *by* Automator and turned into a standalone app that can be executed.  Check out my other question which ultimately led me to this, to see a bigger picture of what I'm trying to accomplish...  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/396139/can-an-automator-workflow-generate-an-application.

Comment: _"...to set the specifics of the event, and, **following its creation,**_ **script its recurrence.**" Why aren't you even piqued by `launchd`.  So, the answer is _Yes_, you _can_ do what you want with Automator, but it's not simple, nor elegant.  "Right tool, right job..." is my motto.

Comment: It's just a question of, if it's possible to do with something I already know and am comfortable with, then obviously that's by far the better option for me.  I didn't want to turn this into a major rabbit hole, I thought this would be a quick and easy thing to do from the start.  It's already consumed way more time & effort than I intended to put into it.  If there truly is no other option then I may look into launchd, it's just not my first choice.  Also, scripting the recurrence was originally what I asked about and can't figure out how to do in AppleScript.

Comment: In case this helps anyone else, I have found this link - https://gregrs-uk.github.io/2018-11-04/macos-calendar-repeating-multiple-events/ - which seems to perhaps be pointing me in the right direction.  We shall see.

Comment: For the record, it seems (thanks to the link I posted before this comment) that I now have a nice and to me, elegant, solution to this in AppleScript.  I will provide a detailed answer once I'm sure it all works as desired.

Comment: Excellent!  You'll have to show me how it's done.

Comment: Dang, so close but one final(?) new hurdle it seems... any thoughts on this?  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/396471/can-applescript-create-an-open-file-alert

Comment: I did explain how to accomplish what you want, using Automator.  I said "AppleScript action...New Calendar Event action...AppleScript action...".  The link you found gives you the format for the expression to set the `recurrence` property (which would be done in the final AppleScript action). The rest of Greg's script isn't helpful (and it's terribly written). I admit, there's going to be a bit of thinking and fiddling around with how to get those three actions doing what they need to. (You'll also need some Automator variable actions). I would offer more specifics, but it's not a quick job.

Comment: I was asking for specifically what the AppleScript would need to be.  And eventually I found it and posted it as my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to get all the way to my ultimate goal of creating repeating calendar events with open file alerts.  But, i did at least solve this question of how to create a repeating calendar event in AppleScript, so here it is.

The main issue is that you can't actually create a repeating event.  You have to create a static event, then *modify* that event to repeat.  Here's the code that is working for me:

```
#Event name & description
set title to "event title"
set taskDescription to "The Description"

# which dates to use?
set startDate to date ("07/21/2020")
set endDate to date ("07/21/2020") -- last date to include

# which calendars contain the events?
set thisCalendar to "Automator"

# how many days in between repeats?
set interval to 2

tell application "Calendar"
    tell calendar thisCalendar
        make new event at end with properties {description:taskDescription, summary:title, start date:startDate + 540 * minutes, end date:startDate + 540 * minutes} # creates event at 9am, modify to suit.
        set theEvents to (every event where its start date is equal to startDate + 540 * minutes)
        set recurrence of item 1 of theEvents to "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=" & interval
    end tell
end tell
```

If you don't have a local calendar called "Automator", then this might give you problems, I'm not sure.  Feel free to change the calendar name if needed.

Comment: If the target calendar does not exist, it will error out.

Comment: Yep, exactly why I mentioned that they may need to change the calendar name.